# Updated Google App Engine and now I have errors with python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Yesterday before updating the Google App Engine SDK, I was able to do `python manage.py runserver` without any problems, but after updating the SDK this morning, I'm getting these errors when trying to do `python manage.py runserver` I'm not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

```
WARNING  2011-10-19 09:18:16,284 dev_appserver.py:4648] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
Warning: You are using a Python runtime (2.6) that is more recent than the production runtime environment (2.5). Your application may use features that are not available in the production environment and may not work correctly when deployed to production.
INFO     2011-10-19 09:18:16,865 appengine_rpc.py:159] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2011-10-19 09:18:19,585 rdbms_sqlite.py:58] Connecting to SQLite database '' with file '/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/.gaedata/rdbms'
WARNING  2011-10-19 09:18:19,587 dev_appserver.py:4648] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/django-blog/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager

  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/django-blog/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute

  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/djangoappengine/management/commands/runserver.py", line 79, in run_from_argv
super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/django-blog/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/django-blog/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 67, in handle
self.run(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/djangoappengine/management/commands/runserver.py", line 154, in run
dev_appserver_main.main([self.progname] + args + [PROJECT_DIR])
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 651, in main
default_partition=default_partition)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4842, in CreateServer
server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4870, in __init__
request_handler_class)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 400, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 411, in server_bind
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x106063190>> ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. All I needed to do was change the port number to a different number. I just chose 8084:

```
python manage.py runserver 8084
```

Comment: that's not exactly solving the problem is it. thats just changing the port number

Comment: use 'sudo lsof -i :8080' to find whats listening on 8080 then deal with it appropriately